# If two symbols in same QGIS layer are too close, show only one?

Tags: qgis, symbology, svg, categorized-renderer, qgis-custom-function

I have a shapefile layer with different underwater, over water and water surface stones. These are often too close to each other to be shown nicely on the print composer generated map.  I use svg symbols for the stones, and they are styled (svg for the stones are chosen) as categorized by a class id in the shapefile table.

How do I get QGIS to show only stones that are, for instance, more than 2mm or xx map units apart?

Comment: Please, have a look at my answer. I didn't test it widely, but it seems to work (I hope it doesn't conflict with the SVG symbols). Let me know if there is any problem!

Comment: How will you decide which one to show? If there are two: one on the left, one on the right, which one should be displayed? The larger one?

Comment: @Fezter I don't know if your comment is for me but, in my approach, I don't make choices. If there are two stones, one on the left, one on the right, they will be displayed if their buffers don't intersect the other corresponding stone; otherwise, the both won't be displayed (since the condition should be verified or not for both stones at the same time).

Comment: @mgri oh I see.

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT** I edited the question because the OP specified that he is working with point shapefiles (the approach will be similar to the original one, though).

---

I propose an approach which only recurs to a geometry generator and a custom function.

## Context

Let's assume to start from this point vector layer representing the stones:

[image]

The layer stores the class ids in the `"CLASS_ID"` field.

## Solution

Go to `Layer Properties | Style` and then:

1. Choose the `Categorized` renderer;
2. Select the `"CLASS_ID"` field (or whatever you want for your situation), without the further clicking on the `Classify` button;
3. Click on the `Change` button for the `Symbol` option.

From the `Symbol selector` dialog, choose a `Geometry generator` as symbol layer type and `Point / MultiPoint` as geometry type. Then click on the `Function Editor` tab:

[image]

Then, click on `New file` and type `show` as the name of the new function:

[image]

You will see that a new function has been created and it is listed on the left side of the dialog. Now, click on the name of the function and replace the default `@qgsfunction` with the following code (don't delete the libraries imported by default):

```py
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def set_dist(distance, layer_name, geom, curr_feat, feature, parent):
    layer  = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    buffered_geom = geom.buffer(distance, -1)
    req = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(buffered_geom.boundingBox())
    show = 1
    for feat in layer.getFeatures(req):
        inGeom = feat.geometry()
        if feat.id() != curr_feat.id() and buffered_geom.intersects(inGeom):
            return False
            break
    return True
```

Once you have done this, click on the `Load` button and you will be able to see the function from the `Custom` Menu of the `Expression` dialog.

Now, type this expression (see the image below as reference):

```py
CASE
WHEN 
show(10,  @layer_name, $geometry, $currentfeature)
THEN 
$geometry
END
```

[image]

You have just run a function which is saying, in an imaginary way:

> *"For the current layer (**@layer_name**), display the geometry (**$geometry**) from the current feature (**$currentfeature**) only when it is more than 10
>   meters apart from any other feature in the same layer."*

The only thing you need to change is the research value for the displaying, which in your case should be 0.002 if you are using a Projected CRS. Therefore, leave the other function parameters as provided.

If you want to set SVG symbols for the stones, go to Simple fill and select the proper option:

[image]

Finally, go back to the `Style` main dialog and click on the `Classify` button (at last!) for setting the changes.

You will see that some stones are not rendered (in the following image I also reported a buffer layer of 10 meters for the sake of clearness):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for once again very clear instructions! I think that this would work very well for me, except one thing: I was not clear enough about this but my objects (stones) are points, not polygons. It is possible to insert the code & expresstion that you give for a point shapefile, but categorizing the points with SVG images, does not work. QGIS automatically tries to make a line as a sub-style for a svg image, and the svg image is not displayed. 

On your result image (with stones of which some are not rendered) I am a bit unclear about why the stones in the middle are not shown?

Comment: @BenjaminDonner please, see my edited answer (I adapted it for a point shapefile).

Comment: For extra points drop the spatial index and use `QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(tmp_geom.buffer(distance,-1).boundingBox())` instead. The index only would speed up things if reused (caching it in the QgsExpressionContext would be possible but more complicated).

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Thank for the hint! I will try to adapt your hint to my code and edit the answer if I will be able to implement it. =)

Comment: Actually, you will want to make sure, that you only hide the symbol if there has already been one painted closeby. you current approach checks if *any* feature is present at all closeby, resulting in no geometry being painted if there are many many very close points. For this you will really have to use `QgsExpression.Function` and override `def funcV2`.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn I edited the code: is it better by now? I tested it on the same point layer and the result is identical to the one from my older code (however, it is obtained with a lighter approach). Thanks again! =)

Comment: Excellent and very detailed answer, what GIS.SE is trying to achieve!

Comment: Looks good. Now you could also pre-calculate `tmp_geom.buffer(distance,-1)` once before the loop.

Comment: Thanks, @Mapperz! I reallly appreciate! There are some other mine answers similar to this one (the last one was posted a couple of minutes ago) that follow a similar approach. Sometimes, writing a detailed description of a solution it's harder than applying it! =)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/m-kuhn/60666113de39e79f644e7331dea686c7

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn thanks again! I think this will be an easier task. It was my first using of custom functions and I directly wrote it from the Field Calculator (without testing it from the Python Console, so I think that some _distraction_ is allowed! :)

Comment: Thank you @mgri  I tried your edited solution - I think it would work but with 20.000 points, it takes over 30 minutes for my computer to render the map with this method :( .   I am trying with FME now to simplify the shapefile data and have received great support for that also, but still not a method that would prioritize the right kind of stones and give the correct output. A friend of mine has been trying with NeighborFinder and testers / buffers, but something is still wrong.

Comment: Thanks @MatthiasKuhn I will try the 2.99 Point cluster also, but I guess it will be hard to prioritize stones in the right order (three different types, type 1 prioritized over type 2, which is prioritized over type 3).

Comment: @BenjaminDonner please, try also my previous solution (the one where there was a QgsSpatialIndex inside the custom function) ([this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/revisions/233597/6) code).

Comment: @BenjaminDonner did you read my last comment? The linked solution uses a spatial index, so it should be faster than the last one.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution is, update to QGIS 2.99/3.0 and use a "Point cluster" renderer.

See this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNL-ZSlc4KM